# Incrementing a number in a <td> with JQuery works only 1 up

Tags: jquery, html-table, increment

Clicking on a + sign i want the number in the nearby `<td>` to go 1 number up.

This works/it seems to work, but only from 0 to 1 and not higher.

This is the code i'm using:

```
$('[id^=plus]').click(function(){
    var cid = $(this).attr('id');
    xx= $('#w'+cid).val();
    number=xx+1;
    $('#w'+cid).html(number); 
});
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: `xx+1` should be `parseInt(xx)+1`. Otherwise you're concatenating strings, not adding.

Comment: You're updating the inner HTML with the new number, but you're not updating the value of `$('#w'+cid).val();`. Hence the value remains the same and it'll seem like it only works once

Comment: `<td>` doesn't have `value`, that's only for inputs.

Comment: UPDATE: got it! (conversion tostring and .text() in stead of .val()
       xx=$('#w'+cid).text();
       number=parseInt(xx)+1;
       var nr=number.toString();
      $('#w'+cid).text(nr);

Comment: Hint: You can probably simplify your script further by using a _relative_ form of DOM navigation instead of referring to actual `id`s.